# expressJS: Limit acceptable content-types

Tags: node.js, express

I have a expressJS API. In POST routes, I only accept two types of headers:

`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

`application/json`

Is there a way that I can express to enforce to only accept the two headers and reject any other `POST` request and respond with some kind of 400 error?

Answer (score 5):

You could use a simple middleware like this on a per-route basis or for all routes:

```
var RE_CONTYPE = /^application\/(?:x-www-form-urlencoded|json)(?:[\s;]|$)/i;
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.method === 'POST' && !RE_CONTYPE.test(req.headers['content-type']))
    return res.send(415);
  next();
});
```